# How to choose components to design a bias tee

Tags: bias

How can I choose components to design a bias tee? What impact do the inductor, capacitor and resistance have on the circuit?

Comment: What AC frequency band do you need to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bias tee is designed to multiplex a DC bias and an RF signal. The resistance is there purely for impedance matching, and the inductor must be chosen to have a high impedance for the frequency of RF which is being used.

It should be designed so that the inductor has a much larger impedance than the characteristic impedance, and the capacitor has a much lower impedance.